# Creating a heatmap in Grafana using Kusto from Azure Data Explorer

Tags: grafana, heatmap, kql

Well, I'm trying to find a way to create a heatmap in Grafana using Kusto.

I found: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v9.0/basics/intro-histograms/#pre-bucketed-data

Which basically said that Kusto is supported. But It doesn't mention the way tabular data should be exposed.

Can anybody guide me with it?

Actually, I have a table with: `Id, Timestamp, Value` where Timestamp changes for all the new series of data. Suppose that I have 10 different Ids then, Timestamp will change every 10 rows.

Example:

```
let test = datatable (Timestamp: datetime, Id: string, Value: decimal)
[
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:00), "machineA_var01", 1,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:00), "machineA_var02", 1.5,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:00), "machineA_var03", 2,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:00), "machineA_var04", 2.5,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:00), "machineA_var05", 5,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:00), "machineA_var06", 3,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:00), "machineA_var07", 2,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:00), "machineA_var08", 6,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:00), "machineA_var09", 3,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:00), "machineA_var10", 4,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:00), "machineA_var11", 5,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:00), "machineA_var12", 6,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:00), "machineA_var13", 1,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:00), "machineA_var14", 13,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:00), "machineA_var15", 3,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:00), "machineA_var16", 5,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:15), "machineB_var01", 3,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:15), "machineB_var02", 7,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:15), "machineB_var03", 8,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:15), "machineB_var04", 6,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:15), "machineB_var05", 8,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:15), "machineB_var06", 2,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:15), "machineB_var07", 6,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:15), "machineB_var08", 2,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:15), "machineB_var09", 3,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:15), "machineB_var10", 3,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:15), "machineB_var11", 3,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:15), "machineB_var12", 4,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:15), "machineB_var13", 6,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:15), "machineB_var14", 2,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:15), "machineB_var15", 8,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:15), "machineB_var16", 5,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:30), "machineC_var01", 6,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:30), "machineC_var02", 3,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:30), "machineC_var03", 8,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:30), "machineC_var04", 9,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:30), "machineC_var05", 3,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:30), "machineC_var06", 6,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:30), "machineC_var07", 5,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:30), "machineC_var08", 6,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:30), "machineC_var09", 4,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:30), "machineC_var10", 7,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:30), "machineC_var11", 1,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:30), "machineC_var12", 3,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:30), "machineC_var13", 5.5,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:30), "machineC_var14", 6,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:30), "machineC_var15", 7,
  datetime(2022-11-30 11:40:30), "machineC_var16", 8,
];
test
```

As you can see I'm printing my information as it is, but this is not enough to be used as a heatmap. My question is, how do I need to transform the source table in order to match the required format by Grafana's heatmap.

I think I'll need to do buckets with the timestamp but how should the data be exposed?

Comment: The point is that I'm only giving the source table as it is. The source query is test and I need to give it the proper format to be consumed from a grafana heatmap.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I edited it again. I missed that per each machine I have different variable values, in this example I have 16, in production I have 36.

Comment: Now you don't have change over time... You don't need to give a full sample.  A few machines, a few variables, a dew timestamps and we're good. Have you thought how you actually want this to be displayed?

Comment: Well, I'd like to display on the X-axis the Timestamp, and on the Y-axis the Id (the point here is that maybe I should split the machine and vars), and I want to do a gradient with the Value from the minimum to the maximum value per each cell.

Comment: That's not how Grafana's heatmap seem to work. X-axis is indeed the timestamp (split to buckets). Y-axis is the value (split to buckets). The color is determined according to the number of occurrences per bucket. Id doesn't play any part here.

Comment: Oh, ok then which alternatives do you propose to me then?

Comment: That's depends on what you're trying to figure out from the graph. It could be min / max / avg / anomalies / relations between machines metrics etc.  P.S. I'm here due to the `kql` tag, not the `grafana` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, not sure how useful it's really going to be and I'm probably get pinged for it again but yet again pivot does the trick:

Adding `| evaluate pivot(Id, max(Value))` to your query yields the following heatmap:

[image: heatmap]